# How can array state be changed?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't understand how to make array passed via combinereducers.

After action dispatched, I want to concatenate input text with array.**(state d)**

An example in redux site says as below, in reducer,and I did just like it.**(checkD_E function)**

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: [
      ...state.todos,
      {
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
       }
    ]
      })
```

d is always updated only to concatenate undefined and last inputed text.

first "undefined" is caused from that initialState isn't read.**(const initialState variable)**

```
    const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
    const BDD_TODO = 'BDD_TODO'
    const DDD_TODO = 'DDD_TODO'
    const EDD_TODO = 'EDD_TODO'
    const {PropTypes} = React;
    const {createStore,combineReducers} = Redux;
    const { Provider, connect} = ReactRedux;
    let store = createStore(rootReducer)

    function changeA(text) {
      return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
    }
    function changeB(text) {
      return { type: BDD_TODO, text }
    }
    function changeD(text) {
      return { type: DDD_TODO, text }
    }
    function changeE(text) {
      return { type: EDD_TODO, text }
    }



    function checkA_B(state={},action){
      switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
          return Object.assign({}, state.checkA_B, {a:action.text})      
        case BDD_TODO:
          return Object.assign({}, state.checkA_B, {b:action.text})   
        case DDD_TODO:
          return state
        default:
          return state
                     }
    }
    function checkD_E(state=[],action){
      switch (action.type) {
        case DDD_TODO:
          return Object.assign({}, state,{
        d: [...state.d,action.text]
          } )   
        case EDD_TODO:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {e:action.text}) 
        default:
          return state

    const initialState ={
      a:"aaa",b:"bbb",c:"ccc",d:[],e:"eee"
    }
    function rootReducer(state = initialState,action){
      return {
        checkA_B:checkA_B(state,action),
        checkD_E:checkD_E(state,action)
      }
    class Clock extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {a:props.a,b:props.b,d:props.d,e:props.e,inputText:props.inputText,onClick:props.onClick};
        this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
      }
      onInput(e){
        this.setState({inputText:e.target.value})   
      }
      onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        this.state.onClick(this.state.inputText)
        this.setState({inputText:""})
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.inputText} onChange={this.onInput} />
          <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
        </form>
        <label>{console.log(this.props.d.map(x=>return x))}</label><label>{this.state.b}</label><label>{this.state.c}</label>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    Clock.propTypes = {

      inputText:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      onClick:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      a:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      b:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      d:PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      e:PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
     return {onClick:(x)=>{
      dispatch(changeD(x))
     }
      }
    }
    function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
      return {d:state.checkD_E.d}
    }
    Clock = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Clock)
    ReactDOM.render(
         <Provider store={store}><Clock /></Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );

index.html
    <div id="root">
      <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
    </div>
```

I guess returned value in mapStatetoProps has to be changed.

But I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two issues.

(1) Your rootReducer doesn't call combineReducer. Consider something like:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  checkA_B: checkA_B,
  checkD_E: checkD_E,
});
```

Note the values are *functions*.

(2) The shape of your state doesn't match your intended reducer structure.
It should be closer to:

```
const initialState = {
  checkA_B: { a: "aaa", b: "bbb" },
  checkD_E: { d: [], e: "eee" },
}
```

The keys of 'initialState' match the keys of the argument of 'combineReducers'.  (I left out 'c' from initialState because it's not clear with which reducer it is associated.)

The good news is, you are correctly making a copy of the state in your reducer.

This may not be every issue with your code, but it should get you closer.

Comment: After state structures in rootReducer, initialState, this.state's init in Clockclass and  mapStatetoProps were changed into same structure as you illustrated, and it worked! And I could reviewed reducer topic on redux site, thank to you. Thanks a lot !!!!      However, ClockClass is initialized in two places, constructor,and reducer. (: (